# How to break out of promise in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise

I have develop a command line programm and its working, but when its done it doesnt finished. i have to control+c an shell to exit

Im new at javascript. Must i divine a callback to say the programm that its done?

My Code:

```
importer.then(function (csvData) {
    var mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(config['phpipam-db']['host'], config['phpipam-db']['user'], config['phpipam-db']['password'], config['phpipam-db']['database']);
    var connection = mySqlConnection.getConnection();

    mySqlConnection.selectSubnets(connection).then(function (customerFolders) {
        var ipv6Data = manager.getIpv6CustomerSubnetsInsertData(csvData, customerFolders);
        var ipv4Data = manager.getIpv4CustomerSubnetsInsertData(csvData, customerFolders);

        mySqlConnection.insertIpv6Subnets(ipv6Data);
    });
});
```

Comment: there's more to your program than this, obviously the problem is elsewhere

Comment: Maybe you will need to close that `connection`?

Comment: What promise library is being used? What version of node?

Answer (score 0):

Add `console.log` statements after `var connection = mySqlConnection.getConnection();` and      `mySqlConnection.insertIpv6Subnets(ipv6Data);`.

If they are executed, the problem is not in the code you posted.

If they are not, you have to check whether your promises get fulfilled.

Comment: the inserts are in the database after i run this

Comment: One of your promises must be not resolved that's why program doesn't stop

Answer (score 0):

Are this methods: `manager.getIpv6CustomerSubnetsInsertData`, `mySqlConnection.insertIpv6Subnets` also returning promises?

If you modify your code like this, can you see Done in the console?

```
importer.then(function (csvData) {
  var mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(config['phpipam-db']['host'], config['phpipam-db']['user'], config['phpipam-db']['password'], config['phpipam-db']['database']);
  var connection = mySqlConnection.getConnection();

  return mySqlConnection.selectSubnets(connection).then(function (customerFolders) {
    var ipv6Data = manager.getIpv6CustomerSubnetsInsertData(csvData, customerFolders);
    var ipv4Data = manager.getIpv4CustomerSubnetsInsertData(csvData, customerFolders);

    return mySqlConnection.insertIpv6Subnets(ipv6Data);
  }).then(function () {
    console.log('Done');
  });
});
```

Comment: but it helped me to find where the problem is.
this promise not resolve 
` importCsv(fileName: string): Promise {
        var stream = fs.createReadStream(fileName);

        var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var result = new Array;
            var csvStream = csv().on("data", function (data) {
                result.push(data[0].split(";"));
            }).on("end", function (end) {
                    resolve(result);
                });
            stream.pipe(csvStream);
        });
        return promise;
    }`

Comment: looks like `'end'` event never happened on `csvStream`

Comment: when i set //mySqlConnection.insertIpv6Subnets(ipv6Data); as a comment the programm ends correctly

Comment: so the problem is inside this method `insertIpv6Subnets`, you would have to show as what is inside.

Comment: `var post = {
                subnet: ip, mask : subnet, sectionId: sectionId, description: description, vrfId: 0, masterSubnetId: masterSubnetId, allowRequests: 0, vlanId: 0, showName: 0, pingSubnet: 0, discoverSubnet: 0, isFolder: 0
            };

            var query = this.getConnection().query('INSERT INTO subnets SET ?', post, function (err, result) {
                
                if (err) {
                    return this.getConnection().rollback(function () {
                        throw err;
                    });
                }
            });`

 here it is

Comment: i cant post the whole function and it looks horrible in the comment.
what i posted is the main part of the function. before i do the insert i go throw an array to pick up infos for the insert statement.

Comment: Was this callback passed to query function invoked? I would advise to return a promise from this function as well and resolve this promise inside callback passed to the query method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83532/discussion-between-marcok-and-mjarosz).